# FX Forwards collateral and discounting

Tags: interest-rates, fx, derivatives, discounting, ois-discounting

What is the market convention for discounting the future cash flows of FX forwards? In particular, I would be interested to know what discounting curves are used for both collateralised and not collateralised FX forwards.

Answer (score 3):

See ['Collateral Posting and Choice of Collateral Currency'](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/46468796_Collateral_Posting_and_Choice_of_Collateral_Currency_-_Implications_for_Derivative_Pricing_and_Risk_Management-) (Theorem 1, in particular) and ['A Note on Construction of Multiple Swap Curves with and without collateral'](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/29780639_A_Note_on_Construction_of_Multiple_Swap_Curves_with_and_without_Collateral) by Fujii et. al., and also ['Cooking with Collateral'](http://janroman.dhis.org/finance/Kreditrisk/Risk_Cooking%20with%20collateralpdf.pdf) by Piterbarg (the basics of unsecured and collateralized cases for forward contracts in general are covered in Piterbarg's paper 'Funding beyond discounting: collateral agreements and derivative pricing').

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest picking up the book "Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives" by Hull. Lots of good knowledge on cash flows pertaining to FX, etc. A bit more quantitative but the discounting aspect is emphasized and I think it will make better sense. If you can't find a download link, lmk :)

Comment: Why not look up the specific question in the book and tell us the answer... referencing Chapter and page number.